# Calculating affine or rigid transform base on a set of matched pairs

Tags: matlab, math, image-processing

I have a set of 200 points (x1,y1) in one image that are matched with other 200 points (x2,y2). How can I find the best transform (affine or rigid) that transfers (x1,y1) to (x2,y2)? Any function in MATLAB?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MATLAB's [**mldivide**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) or backslash "**\**" operator to solve for the system of equations using its least squares implementation. Below is a simple approach.

```
function affinefit

    % Define number of points and a test affine transformation to estimate 
    n = 200;
    A = [0, -1; 1, 0]; % 90 degree rotation about z-axis
    b = [2; 4]; % Offset

    % Generate initial and transformed points points
    xy1 = rand(2, n);
    xy2 = A * xy1 + repmat(b, 1, n);

    % Perform least squares fit on A(1,1), A(1,2), and b(1)
    Ab1 = [xy1', ones(n, 1)] \ xy2(1,:)';

    % Perform least squares fit on A(2,1), A(2,2), and b(2)
    Ab2 = [xy1', ones(n, 1)] \ xy2(2,:)';

    % Extract least squares estimate
    Ae = [Ab1(1:2)'; Ab2(1:2)'];
    be = [Ab1(3); Ab2(3)];

    % Print results
    fprintf('Truth Transformation\n');
    fprintf('A =\n'); disp(A);
    fprintf('b =\n'); disp(b);

    fprintf('Estimated Transformation\n');
    fprintf('A =\n'); disp(Ae);
    fprintf('b =\n'); disp(be);

end
```

which has the following output

```
>> affinefit
Truth Transformation
A =
     0    -1
     1     0

b =
     2
     4

Estimated Transformation
A =
    0.0000   -1.0000
    1.0000   -0.0000

b =
    2.0000
    4.0000
```

Note, there are other things that you should take care of such as outliers in which case you may want to combine this with an outlier detector such as [**RANSAC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC).